Issues with Estimating Parameters in Gaussian Time Series Data Using R
I am working on a project involving time series data with Gaussian noise, and I am encountering an issue with parameter estimation. Specifically, my estimated parameter \psi differs significantly from the true value used in the data generation.
I generate Gaussian noise data using the following function in R:
simulate_data_gaussian <- function(T, a0, b0, psi0, sigma0) {
  epsilon <- rnorm(T - 1, mean = 0, sd = sigma0)
  y <- numeric(T)
  e <- numeric(T)
  e[1] <- rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = sigma0)
  y[1] <- a0 + b0 * 1 + e[1]
  for (t in 2:T) {
    e[t] <- psi0 * e[t-1] + epsilon[t-1]
    y[t] <- a0 + b0 * t + e[t]
  }
  return(y)
}

I use this objective function to estimate parameters a, b, and psi:
f_objective <- function(a, b, psi, y, T) {
  residuals <- y[2:T] - a - b * (2:T) - psi * (y[1:(T-1)] - a - b * (1:(T-1)))
  return(sum(residuals^2) / T)
}

The complete code for the simulation is below:
# Simulated data (Gaussian)
set.seed(123)
T <- 100  # Sample size
a0 <- 1
b0 <- 2
psi0 <- 0.5
sigma0 <- 1
y <- simulate_data_gaussian(T, a0, b0, psi0, sigma0)

# Objective function f(a,b,psi)
f_objective <- function(a, b, psi, y, T) {
  residuals <- y[2:T] - a - b * (2:T) - psi * (y[1:(T-1)] - a - b * (1:(T-1)))
  return(sum(residuals^2) / T)
}


# Analytical solution for a and b in terms of psi
solve_ab_psi <- function(psi, y, T) {
  # Construct the system of linear equations for a and b
  A <- matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
  b_vec <- numeric(2)
  
  for (t in 2:T) {
    A[1, 1] <- A[1, 1] + 1 + psi^2
    A[1, 2] <- A[1, 2] + t + psi * (t - 1)
    A[2, 1] <- A[2, 1] + t + psi * (t - 1)
    A[2, 2] <- A[2, 2] + t^2 + (t - 1)^2
    
    b_vec[1] <- b_vec[1] + y[t] + psi * y[t-1]
    b_vec[2] <- b_vec[2] + t * y[t] + (t - 1) * psi * y[t-1]
  }
  
  # Solve for a(psi) and b(psi)
  solution <- solve(A, b_vec)
  a_psi <- solution[1]
  b_psi <- solution[2]
  
  return(c(a_psi, b_psi))
}

# Function to compute f(a(psi), b(psi), psi)
f_psi <- function(psi, y, T) {
  ab <- solve_ab_psi(psi, y, T)
  a_psi <- ab[1]
  b_psi <- ab[2]
  return(f_objective(a_psi, b_psi, psi, y, T))
}

# Generate psi values and evaluate f(psi)
psi_values <- seq(-1, 1, by = 0.01)
f_values <- sapply(psi_values, f_psi, y = y, T = T)

# Plot f(psi)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(psi = psi_values, f_value = f_values)
ggplot(df, aes(x = psi, y = f_value)) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Objective Function f(a(psi), b(psi), psi)", 
       x = expression(psi), y = "f(psi)") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

And the resulting estimations are shown in the figure below:

Issue: Despite generating data with psi0=0.5, my estimated psi is significantly different from 0.5 (0.98). I validated the generated data and objective function, but the discrepancy persists.
Question: Can someone help me understand why the estimated psi is different from the true value psi0? What might be going wrong in my estimation process? Are there any common pitfalls or debugging steps I should consider?
